# Footlight Fiend vs. Rising Populace Trigger order

Tags: magic-the-gathering

While drafting WAR we encountered a situation we didn't know how to resolve. Imagine the following situation:

- The opponent attacks with [Rising Populace](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=460956) and a 1/1 creature.
- I block the [Rising Populace](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=460956) with [Footlight Fiend](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Footlight%20Fiend) and the 1/1 creature of the opponent with a 1/1 creature myself.

After the combat damage is dealt, the Populace gets a +1/+1 counter while I want to deal 1 damage to the Populace to kill it beforehand. Basically the triggers occur at the same time, so which ability resolves first? The Fiend's since I have priority? Will the Populace die or become a 3/3?

Comment: You have played mixed RNA/WAR draft?

Comment: Yes we often do some kind of Standard Draft.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> 603.3b If multiple abilities have triggered since the last time a player received priority, each player, in APNAP order, puts triggered abilities they control on the stack in any order they choose. (See rule 101.4.) Then the game once again checks for and resolves state-based actions until none are performed, then abilities that triggered during this process go on the stack. This process repeats until no new state-based actions are performed and no abilities trigger. Then the appropriate player gets priority.

The attacking player is the active player, so Rising Populace's trigger is put on the stack first, followed by Footlight Fiend's trigger, *which will resolve first*. After the ability resolves, state-based actions will see a 2/2 with 2 damage, and kill the Rising Populace before its own ability can come to the rescue.